# The containment between the Schwartz space, its dual, and the Lebesgue space $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory

I read from my note that
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}).$$

Where $\mathcal{S}$ is the space of rapidly decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}$, 
$\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}.$

I could not identify the proof of above in my functional analysis text. Could anyone give me a proof of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi \in \def\S{\mathcal S}\def\R{\mathbf R}\S(\R)$ is given, note that by definition of rapidly decreasing, we have $\phi \in C(\R)$, that is $\phi$ is continuous - hence measurable - and moreover for some $M \in \R$: 
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{\phi(x)}(1 + \abs x^2) \le M $$
Hence
$$ \int_\R \abs{\phi}^2 \,d\lambda \le M^2 \int_\R (1 + \abs x^2)^{-2}\, d\lambda(x) = \frac{M^2\pi}2 < \infty \tag 1 $$
so $\phi \in L^2(\R)$. *Thus we have shown $\S(\R) \subseteq L^2(\R)$.*

To prove $L^2(\R)\subseteq \S'(\R)$, let $\phi \in L^2(\R)$ *be an arbitrary function*, note that for any $\psi \in \S(\R)$ we have by the above, that 
$$ \abs{\int_\R \phi\psi\,d\lambda} \le \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{\phi}_2 \norm{\psi}_2 \le \norm{\phi}_2 \frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt 2}\cdot \sup_x \abs{(1 + \abs x^2)\psi(x)} $$
As the latter is a continuous seminorm on $\S(\R)$, this proves that $\psi \mapsto \int_\R \phi\psi\, d\lambda$ is continuous on $\S(\R)$, therefore $\phi \in \S'(\R)$.

Comment: not too sure about the last inequality...could you explain?

Comment: In the second displayed equation - to be marked (1) - we have shown that for $\phi \in \S(\R)$, 
$$ \|\phi\|_2^2 \le \sup_x \abs{(1 + \abs x^2)\phi(x)}^2 \cdot \frac \pi 2 $$
(the $\sup$ is called $M$ there), now take the square root.

Comment: Because $$\int (1 + x^2)^{-2} \, dx = \frac 12\left( \frac{x}{1 + x^2} + \arctan x \right) $$

Comment: where is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from?

Comment: $[\arctan x]_{-\infty}^\infty = \pi$.

Comment: I think the last line should be $\sup_x|(1+|x|^2)\phi(x)|\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\|\psi\|_2$

Comment: No, as $\phi \in L^2(\R)$ only, the sup in $\phi$ need not exist.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you please add that to your solution?

Comment: I think, it may be just notational irritations, let me change add something, hope it helps ...

Comment: my understanding is...Basically, you mean, if $\phi\in (L^2)^*$, then $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^2$. Then, as earlier deduced, $\mathcal{S}\subset L^2$, which implies $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional on $\mathcal{S}$, and so $\phi\in\mathcal{S}'$.

Comment: Right, that is what I argue in the second part.